# Overclocking software for AMD?

Tags: overclocking

I know that software-based overclocking is a bad idea - the problem is I am in a bit of a predicament. I am busy with an AI project that is due soon.

I am busy running some very CPU intensive simulations and need to get these done faster than the expected finishing time. These simulations cannot be stopped or resumed, so I absolutely cannot reset my PC. I am hoping to be able to use a software-based overclocking solution to speed up the simulations; at the same time I cannot afford to have the PC hang from the software overclocking.

Here is a screenshot from Core Temp:

[image: Core Temp screenshot]

Comment: You might be able to overclock a little with no problem, but if reliability is absolutly key to your work as you seem to imply, then I would maybe focus your future efforts on getting a faster computer or workstation that can serve your project time frames.

Comment: *These simulations cannot be stopped or resumed, so I absolutely cannot reset my PC* having said these - overclocking without stability tests is a bad, bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to have tell my supervisor that there was no way for me to run the simulations faster. They've been running for 41 hours now. I'm going to try look into renting some sort of supercomputer. Anyone know of any? (I only need one core)

Comment: I agree with @Troggy - you need a high end workstation.  I won't make specific parts recommendations in this thread because that would be a little tacky, though.

Comment: Yah, if this is a work machine, I would explain the situation to your manager.  This is a perfect case for the purchase of a workstation or super computing rental expense if time deadlines are priority.

Answer (score 2):

I would use AMDs overclocking software if I absolutely had to overclock. Here is a direct link to the download. http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/AMD-Overdrive-Download-104851.html Let me know how this works out for you with a comment!

P.S. Try not to melt your CPU...(This was your warning) :D

-Good Luck

Comment: Here is the link to AMD's site: [link](http://game.amd.com/us-en/drivers_overdrive.aspx). i second the warning to not damage your computer, especially if you are dead set on not doing stability tests

Comment: @Xantec interestingly the AMD link has an older version

Comment: thanks for the link, just my luck that my motherboard is not compatible